# Dataframe values to columns with datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas when the values are voltage, the columns are current and the index is a datetime index. I want to change columns to voltage and values to current to each datetime, but i don't want to iterate for each datetime value.

It is a lineal interpolation. In each minute the columns are x and the values are y=f(x), which f is a sum of some iv photovoltaic curves. I want to know if there is an easy way to make the columns y and the values x=f(y) without interpolate each value by itself

The inicial dataframe is this:

```
|                          | 0.000000   |  0.333333 |   0.666667|    1.000000|
|--------------------------|------------|-----------|-----------|------------|
|2021-08-14 11:37:00+02:00 | 735.137413 | 732.315522 |729.421353|  726.447714|
|2021-08-14 11:38:00+02:00 | 733.769157 | 730.948554 |728.055935|  725.084153|
|2021-08-14 11:39:00+02:00 | 734.043764 | 731.234371 |728.354040|  725.395789|
|2021-08-14 11:40:00+02:00 | 733.273464 | 730.472126 |727.600712|  724.652374|
|2021-08-14 11:41:00+02:00 | 733.246622 | 730.449145 |727.581971|  724.638308|
```

And the objective dataframe look like this

```
|                          |    735   |   730    |    725   |    720  |
|--------------------------|----------|----------|----------|---------|
|2021-08-14 11:37:00+02:00 | 0.016232 | 0.600022 | 1.162283 | 1.722764|
|2021-08-14 11:38:00+02:00 |-0.145459 | 0.442641 | 1.009439 | 1.570270|
|2021-08-14 11:39:00+02:00 |-0.113457 | 0.476184 | 1.044597 | 1.607993|
|2021-08-14 11:40:00+02:00 |-0.205442 | 0.388141 | 0.960698 | 1.525988|
|2021-08-14 11:41:00+02:00 |-0.208924 | 0.385550 | 0.959043 | 1.525231|
```

I can do it by interpolating each datetime value, but i can't do it as fast as i would with a datetime of a year with minute resolution. My question is if there is a function in pandas that allow me to make this transformation without iterating each value of the index.

Comment: You want to change values ok, but you did not disclose any logic by which that change happens.

Comment: It is a lineal interpolation. In each minute the columns are x and the values are y=f(x), which f is a sum of some iv photovoltaic curves. I want to know if there is an easy way to make the columns y and the values x=f(y) without interpolate each value by itself